# Why does Java Collections have helpers for 0 or 1 but not more elements?

Tags: java, collections, guava

If I want an empty map or a one element map, Java Collections has a method for that. Why is there no method for more than one element? What's the best way to create a static final map with 2 elements in it? I know I can do something like:

```
private static final Map<String, String> MAP = new HashMap<String, String>() {
    { put("a", "b"); put("c", "d"); }
};
```

But then Eclipse complains about the serialVersionUID...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question fully - do you want to insert a whole group of elements in one call? Like a `put` that can put more than one element into the map at one time?

Comment: @birryree Yeah, I want to create the static final map in one call, or in the least amount of boilerplate possible. Even with the put you describe you have to declare a serialVersionUID for eclipse to be happy.

Comment: @Jeremy Better yet wait for Java 8 with lambda support :) It's been way too long!

Comment: You could just let Eclipse add a serial number...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason `Collections` has methods for 0 and 1 entry maps is because they are special cases... the empty `Map` is an immutable singleton for example.

For what you want to do, though, I'd strongly recommend using [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com). Its `Immutable*` collections (`ImmutableMap` specifically) are what you want I think:

```
private static final ImmutableMap<String, String> MAP = ImmutableMap.of(
    "a", "b",
    "c", "d");
```

You can do the above for small maps, and for bigger maps you can write:

```
private static final ImmutableMap<String, String> MAP = 
    ImmutableMap.<String, String>builder()
      .put("a", "b")
      .put("b", "c")
      ...
      .put("y", "z")
      .build();
```

If you don't use Guava, you'll still likely want to ensure that this map can't be changed. This is a lot uglier:

```
private static final Map<String, String> MAP;

static {
  Map<String, String> temp = new HashMap<String, String>();
  temp.put("a", "b");
  temp.put("b", "c");
  MAP = Collections.unmodifiableMap(temp);
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer, just learnt quite a bit about collections, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Mutable objects like maps chan be changed even if they are static and final. Final just means that the reference to the object can't change. You don't need to add the objects on initialization. The map can be added to and otherwise modified in other areas of the code, but you cannot assign a different object to the variable `MAP` later.

If you want it to be initialized with two items, you can add them in a static block after the declaration.

```
static { 
   MAP.put("a", "b"); 
   MAP.put("c", "d");
}
```

[This article](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/2238491) has some good information on how static blocks work.

If you want an immutable map with two items, you can use a static block again like so:

```
private static final Map<String, String> MAP;
static {
    Map<String, String> tempMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    tempMap.put("a", "b");
    tempMap.put("c", "d");
    MAP = Collections.unmodifiableMap(tempMap);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (modified version of what Mark Storer wrote):

```
private static final Map<String, String> Map = buildMap();

private static Map<String, String> buildMap() {
  Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
  map.put("a", "b");
  map.put("c", "d");
  return Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
}
```

Comment: (That or use a `static` intialiser, depending on taste. Also, might (or might not) want to put in a capacity for the map, which IIRC should be at least one third larger than the size.)

Answer (score 0):

Use the return value of a static function:

```
private static final Map<String, String> Map = buildMap();

private static Map<String, String> buildMap() {
  Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
  map.put("a", "b");
  map.put("c", "d");
  return map;
}
```

EDIT: Nope.  My C/C++ "const" thinking is showing.  A final variable may only be assigned once, but the object assigned to that variable is still quite mutable.

Answer (score 0):

If they provide 0..N for any N you would be asking why isn't N+1 supported. N=0 and N=1 are easily handled special cases.

Comment: What do you mean, there are only three cases: 0, 1, more than 1